# Unit Testing AngularJS Service

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to test my AngularJS service that has a dependency on `$http`.

When using `$httpBackend` to mock that AJAX post (`whenPOST`), does the object you post determine the response?

Here is my service and my test for example:

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    var app = angular.module('cs');

    app.service('PlateCheckService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
                return $http.post('PlateCheck/Index', {
                    plateNumber: plateNumber
                }).then(function (response) {
                    return {
                        message: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'Clean' : 'Hot',
                        alertClass: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

}());
```

**Tests**

```
/// <reference path="../libs/angular-1.0.8/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../libs/angular-1.0.8/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../libs/jasmine-1.3.0/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../app.js" />
/// <reference path="../services/plate-check-service.js" />

describe('Plate Check Service', function () {
    var httpBackend,
        service;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('cs');

        inject(function ($httpBackend, PlateCheckService) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            httpBackend.whenPOST('PlateCheck/Index', { plateNumber: '123456' }).respond({
                response: {
                    message: 'Clean',
                    alertClass: 'alert-success'
                }
            });
            httpBackend.whenPOST('PlateCheck/Index', { plateNumber: '123456789' }).respond({
                response: {
                    message: 'Hot',
                    alertClass: 'alert-danger'
                }
            });

            service = PlateCheckService;
        });
    });

    it('Should return a clean plate.', function () {
        var result;

        service.checkPlate('123456').then(function (response) {
            result = response;
        });

        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result.message).toBe('Clean');
        expect(result.alertClass).toBe('alert-success');
    });
});
```

**Test Results**

```
Test 'Plate Check Service:Should return a clean plate.' failed
    Expected 'Hot' to be 'Clean'.
    Expected 'alert-danger' to be 'alert-success'.
in D:\Code\Scripts\angular\specs\plate-check-service-specs.js (line 35)

0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (chutzpah).

========== Total Tests: 0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total ==========
```

It looks like it is not taking into account the `plateNumber` I am passing to the service which posts it to the server.

I would have expected this test to pass.

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a `when` instead of a `expect`.  `$httpBackend` can run in two different modes.  From [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend):

> There are two ways to specify what test data should be returned as
>   http responses by the mock backend when the code under test makes http
>   requests:
>
> - $httpBackend.expect - specifies a request expectation
> - $httpBackend.when - specifies a backend definition
>
> **Request Expectations vs Backend Definitions** Request expectations provide a way to make assertions about requests made by the
>   application and to define responses for those requests. The test will
>   fail if the expected requests are not made or they are made in the
>   wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

If you change your setup to use an `expectPOST`, then the mock will take the request into account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should the `expect` go in the `it` or in the `beforeEach` like the `when`? Also, when would you use one over the other?

Comment: When you want to use the response use `expect`.  You can put set in the `beforeEach` or in the `it` depending on how many tests are sharing your setup.  However, it is preferable to localize setup near the test (as much as possible).

Comment: In the docs it says "Backend definitions ... just returns a trained response if a request is made" so I don't understand why backend definitions are not working in this case?